# Add only five elements in the listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to add only five numbers in the listview,if i enter 6th number it has to show one
   toast message that is my requirement.i am using arraylist in the listview .i wrote some
   code but it doesn't work.please help
   me

My code is

```
  private EditText nuberText;
private Button addBtn;
private ListView listShowContacts;

private Builder dialog;

//ReceivingNumbers numbers = new ReceivingNumbers();
private ArrayList<String> contactNumber = new ArrayList<String>();


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ;
int clickCounter=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addordelnumbers);
    listShowContacts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.showlist);
    contactNumber =ReceivingNumbers.getNumbers();
    Log.e("ContactNumbers",contactNumber.get(0));

    setUpView();


    listShowContacts.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            dialog = new Builder(AddOrDelNumbers.this);

            dialog.setTitle("ALERT");
            dialog.setMessage(contactNumber.get(arg2)+"   Do You Want to Delete This Number?");

            dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     contactNumber.remove(arg2);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }


            });
            dialog.show();


            return false;
        }

    });


//  adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactNumber);
//  listShowContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
}
private void setUpView(){

    addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    nuberText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterNumber);

    if(contactNumber.size()>4){
    adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactNumber);
    listShowContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enter only five numbers",100).show();
    }



    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            addItemList();

        }
    });

}

private void addItemList(){
    if(isInputValid(nuberText)){

        contactNumber.add(nuberText.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
private boolean isInputValid(EditText ed){
    if(nuberText.getText().toString().trim().length()<1){
        nuberText.setError("please enter number");
        return false;

    }else{
        return true;
    }
}


 i wrote like this,but it not working



    if(contactNumber.size()>4){
    adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>       
     (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactNumber);
    listShowContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enter only five   
    numbers",100).show();
    }
```

Comment: Put a Flag on arraylist size and display a toast accordingly.

Comment: please send some code according to this

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

After adding item call the method again if you use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` it's refresh only listview it'll not check the condition.

```
private void addItemList(){
    if(isInputValid(nuberText)){

        contactNumber.add(nuberText.getText().toString());
        setUpView();

    }
}
```

and

```
private void setUpView(){

    addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    nuberText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterNumber);

    if(contactNumber.size() <= 5){
    adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactNumber);
    listShowContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enter only five numbers",100).show();
    }



    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            addItemList();

        }
    });

}
```

then your condition is `if(contactNumber.size() > 4)` this will execute size greater than 4. if you add 6 that condition will execute it'll not give toast. Use `if(contactNumber.size() <= 5)`